# Ember Push Range To Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

I have to variables in my template "from" and "to" that loops through array of data in a select tag.

I want to push the "from", "to" and the values in between to another array.

Like if the array was like this

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

If the user chose "2" in the from field and "6" in the "to" field, I want to push "2" and "6" and the data in between so the result would be:

```
[2,3,4,5,6]
```

I tried to this

```
result : [],
time : Ember.computed('from', 'to', function() {
    this.get('formData.time').forEach(time => {
    // formData.time is a service from which i'm getting the array
        if (time == this.get('from')) this.get('result').push(time)
        this.get('result').push(time)
        if (time == this.get('to')) this.get('result').push(time)
    })
    return this.get('result')
})
```

but it pushes all the array, I know it's a wrong approach that i'm doing
but I couldn't find the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to give you a example:

you can:

```
result : [],
time : Ember.computed('from', 'to', function() {
    var from = this.get('from'), to = this.get('to')
    var fromIndex = this.get('formData.time').indexOf(from), toIndex = this.get('formData.time')
  this.get('formData.time').forEach((item, index) => index >= fromIndex && index <= toIndex && this.get('result').push(item))
  return this.get('result')
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there any article you know that explains the "forEach" loop in detail ? it might help in the future cuz all i thought "forEach" could do is "array.forEach((item, index) => { // simple stuff to do })

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/foreach-method-array-javascript @Luffy Let's try and be a little more welcoming to newer users.

Comment: @lix: possibly, but I wonder if we can still ask newer users to use a search engine? It is essential for their progression as software engineers, and doing it for them won't scale very well (as dedicated volunteers will often tell you).

Answer (score 4):

I know there is already an accepted answer, however, there is no real reason to use a loop for this sort of processing. Ember prototypes the slice method which extracts a sub portion of an array from a given start and end index. You can use the MDN for references. Below is an example of how to use the slice method.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

```
result : [],
time : Ember.computed('from', 'to', function() {
    var { from, to } = this.getProperties(['from', 'to']);
    var fromIndex = this.get('formData.time').indexOf(from);
    var toIndex = this.get('formData.time').indexOf(to);
    var data = this.get('formData.time').slice(fromIndex, toIndex + 1);
    return this.get('result').concat(data);
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Try is it:

:)

```
const a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
const from = 2, to = 6
const value = []
const fromIndex = a.indexOf(from), toIndex = a.indexOf(to)
a.forEach((item, index) => index >= fromIndex && index <= toIndex && value.push(item))
console.log(value)
```

Comment: i don't get your code could you please please explain it to me, i'm trying to apply the principle in Ember and it's been giving me a bunch of errors

Comment: It Worked .. that's awesome but could you explain it to me, it's like a new way to loop through data using "forEach" .. Thanks that was amazing

Comment: About the code, I get the index of array, so I use the "from index" and "to index" to loop through data.